# how to get value from the JSON Arrary AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want to get value of `retVal`

`{"result":[[{"RetVal":"1"}],30]}`

I have tried the following but it is showing undefined

```js
success: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                var result = data.result;

                alert(result.RetVal);
                alert(result[0][0].retVal);
                alert(result[0].RetVal);
```

Comment: If down below answer is not solve your problem. Then, consider to add some more code and details in your question. @Rajesh Parbat

Comment: seems like a typo: `.retVal != .RetVal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of the `RetVal` property from the JSON data you provided, you can try using the following code:

```
success: function (data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data)); // this line is optional, it just displays the entire JSON data in an alert

  var result = data.result; // this gets the "result" property from the JSON data
  var retVal = result[0][0].RetVal; // this gets the "RetVal" property from the first element in the first element of the "result" array

  alert(retVal); // this displays the value of the "RetVal" property in an alert
}
```

In the code above, `data.result` returns the `result` property of the JSON data, which is an array with two elements:

1. A nested array containing a single object with a `RetVal` property
2. A number (`30` in this case)

To get the `RetVal` property from the first element of the result array, we access it using the following syntax: `result[0][0].RetVal`.

Note that property names in JavaScript are case-sensitive, so you need to use the correct capitalization when accessing the `RetVal` property (i.e., `RetVal`, not `retVal`).